# How (if possible) can I measure a pulsed signal with a lock-in amplifier?

Tags: experimental-physics, applied-physics

I am trying to simulate free-field acoustic conditions using a pulse technique - i.e. send an acoustic pulse from source to receiver, and measure only the initial response, cutting out all reflections (which appear later on oscilloscope due to time delay). However, my signal has a bunch of noise, including a large 1st harmonic (electrical signal conducted through water), where I am trying to measure only the second harmonic. I am using a sine wave which is amplitude modulated to a pulse.

With normal continuous wave measurements, I use a lock-in amplifier to cut out the noise, however, this has the side-effect of accepting all reflections as well, which result in resonant peaks dependent on the container size.

I was wondering, therefore, if there is a way to time-gate the signal using a lock-in amplifier and only measure a pulse window, rather than averaging over a whole cycle. Is this possible? I can't find any documentation on it if so.

Just for reference as far as specific Lock-in Amplifiers are concerned, I have an SRS SR830 model, as well as an SRS SR865A, and a Zurich HF2LI.

Comment: This type of measurement is commonly done in Time-gated single photon counting experiments, but I'm unclear on exactly what you're trying to measure.  Is your primary focus the timing of when the first pulse gets there?

Comment: Not really, it just needs to be gated so that the lock-in can correctly measure the first pulse while ignoring the others. Can you link to an example of what you're talking about? Thanks.

Comment: Does your Zurich have the Boxcar integrator add-on? That’s what you need. If not, they would let you buy it.

Comment: You could also use a pulse generator with a mixer, timed to pick out your first pulse (like a “gate”). You would then send the result to the lock-in.

Comment: Might [DSP.se] be better suited for this question?